# Tensorflow: Does object detection API returns detected object id

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I am using the `tensorflow` `object detection api` on windows system and it has been working fine. I am using the pre-trained model as of now which is `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017`. It is easily detecting all the objects in a given input video. I wanted to record time of each object so lets say, if in a video a car enters at `00:05` and leaves at `00:15` which means that it was in for `10secs`.

To achieve this, I was looking if there is anything like id of each detected object which the API returns so that I can start a timer from the code to calculate the time of an object. Is there any already built functionality for this in the API.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tensorflow Object detection does not provide such functionality, but you can user KFC algorithm(easily available using Open CV) to track the object.

https://www.docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d2/dff/classcv_1_1TrackerKCF.html

or You can implement SORT above object detection API which uses Kalman Filter but easy to integrate.

https://github.com/abewley/sort/blob/master/sort.py

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any reference example for this.

Comment: @SAndrew, Follow the link for Keras implementation of yolo3 and sort tracking: https://github.com/Qidian213/deep_sort_yolov3

Answer (score 0):

The Tensorflow Object Detection API does not currently track objects between frames.